# How to enable HTTP2 for Wildfly 10.1

Tags: wildfly, http2, wildfly-10

I am trying to enable HTTP2 on wildfly 10.1 .

According to [official declarations](https://wildfly.org/news/2016/08/19/WildFly10-1-Released/) all I had to do was point the browser to port 8443. I did so and indeed the test certs were automatically created.

From the logs:

> [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (default I/O-3) WFLYDM0113:
>   Generated self signed certificate at
>   C:\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\standalone\configuration\application.keystore.
>   Please note that self signed certificates are not secure, and should
>   only be used for testing purposes. Do not use this self signed
>   certificate in production.

The listeners are configured to allow HTTP2.

```
<server name="default-server">
 <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
 <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" enable-http2="true"/>
 <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
     <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
     <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
     <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
 </host>
</server>
```

When I use developer tools to inspect the transfer protocol of the first page I see tha it is still using **http/1.1**

[image]

Comment: You may want to check with different browsers because if the browser doesn't support http2 it will automatically fallback to http/1.1

Comment: Do you have solution for this? I'm facing the exact same issue